# Why Can't PDI find/run my package stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, pentaho, procedure, pdi

community! This is my first question, please go easy on me! :)

I have an ETL process on PDI to orchestrate calls on procedures stored in a package in Oracle.

Some procedures are ready and run normally on PL/SQL Developer.
When I call them using pentaho, either using the job 'SQL' or the transformations 'Execute SQL Script' or 'Call DB procedure' I always get an error related to "can't find the procedure", like: "ORA-00904: "PKG_CARGA_DIARIA_SABARA"."FUN_HELLO_WORLD": invalid identifier" or "ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG_CARGA_DIARIA_SABARA.FUN_HELLO_WORLD' must be declared".

Please, what am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6t3Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yYss.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm2Vg.png)

EDIT 1: I'm using the user that created the package both to test it in PL/SQL Developer and to connect to the database in PDI.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code, I get - no surprise - the same message:

```
SQL> select "PKG_CARGA_DIARIA_SABARA"."FUN_HELLO_WORLD" from dual;
select "PKG_CARGA_DIARIA_SABARA"."FUN_HELLO_WORLD" from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "PKG_CARGA_DIARIA_SABARA"."FUN_HELLO_WORLD": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

It means that function in that package (which means the package itself) isn't accessible to me. Of course it isn't, I don't have it in my schema. Looks like you don't have it either.

Saying that it works in PL/SQL Developer, I suppose you're connected as package's owner. If user - who tries to call that function - connected to the database in PDI (whatever it is, I don't know/use it) isn't the same as the one you used in PL/SQL Developer and it wasn't granted EXECUTE privilege on the package, then it can't "see" nor execute it.

Therefore:

- try to connect as package's owner
- if you must connect as someone else, let owner grant EXECUTE privilege, while you should (in PDI) precede package name with the owner name

Comment: Hi Littlefoot!

Thank you very much for your answer, however I'm certain to be using the same user, should have posted this info with the question by the way.

I'm new to how oracle separates objects, there might be an error there. I created this package and procedures without defining a schema, and with the very same process user I use in both PL/SQL Developer and Pentaho Connection. I though since I can access it in PL/SQL, no reason not to in PDI, does it make sense?

Comment: You don't have to specify owner (schema) when creating objects in Oracle; by default, the belong to user (schema) you're currently connected to. As of PDI, I - unfortunately - can't help as I don't use it.

Comment: I get it. I'm testing some object creation and destruction through PDI and it seems to work fine, just can't get around using the procedure inside the package really, at least for now. Thanks for all the help, Littlefoot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it here! Will post so that anyone can use the answer.

PDI Doesn't automatically consider the schema from the database connection user, you have to specifically add it to your code inside the SQL job.

So: "BEGIN .<procedure name; END;" yelds the error, even though I was running with the procedure and package owner.

And: "BEGIN ..<procedure name; END;" will work it out just fine.

Hope it helps someone, tks!